# Proving homeomorphism in Möbius strip

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, mobius-band

> Consider the Möbius strip defined by the following equivalence relation on the subspace $[0,1]\times]-a,a[$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$:
>
> $$(x,y)\sim (x',y')\implies (x,y)=(x',y')\vee|x'-x|=1\:\text{and}\:y'=-y$$
>
> So the Möbius strip would be $M=[0,1]\times]-a,a[\setminus\sim$ be the quotient space with the following quotient map:
>
> $$p:[0,1]\times]-a,a[\to M$$
>
> Let$V=p(([0,1]\setminus\{\frac{1}{2}\})\times]-a,a[)$ and  $\psi:V\to\psi(V)=]\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}[\times]-a,a[$ be given as follows:
>
> $$\psi([(x,y)])=\begin{cases}(x+1,-y)\:\:\text{if}\:\: x<\frac{1}{2}\\(x,y)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\text{if}\:\:\:x>\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that $\psi$ is well defined and is a homeomorphism.

I am having trouble proving $\psi$ to be continuous and open.

I noticed that if $p\sim p'$ then $\psi(p)=\psi(p')$ so the function is well defined and bijective.

If I build the following translation:

$$f:\psi(V)\to [0,1]\times]-a,a[\\(x,y)\to(x-\frac{1}{2},y)$$

Then I can build the following function:

$$p\circ f(\psi(V)):]\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}[\times]-a,a[\to M$$

I think this last construction could prove continuity if I could assure $\psi$ to be open. However I am not seeing how to define open sets in M.

**Question**:

How should I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m going to try first to give a slightly different approach that may make it a bit clearer exactly what is going on here.

Let $A=(-a,a)$ and $M_0=[0,1]\times A$. The equivalence relation $\sim$ identifies $\{0\}\times A$, the left edge of $M_0$, with $\{1\}\times A$, the right edge of $M_0$, after turning it upside down. It’s that turning upside down, by identifying $\langle 0,y\rangle$ with $\langle 1,-y\rangle$, that corresponds to the half twist in a physical Möbius strip.

Let $U_0=\left[0,\frac12\right)\times A$, $U_1=\left(\frac12,1\right]\times A$, and $U=U_0\cup U_1$; $U$ is what is left of $M_0$ after we cut out the segment $\left\{\frac12\right\}\times A$. Now flip $U_0$ around the $x$-axis (or, if you prefer, reflect it in the $x$-axis) by the map

$$r:U_0\to U_0:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\langle x,-y\rangle\;,$$

and then translate the result one unit to the right by the map

$$t:U_0\to\Bbb R^2:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\langle x+a,y\rangle\;.$$

Let $U'=U_1\cup(t\circ r)[U_0]$, and define

$$f:U\to U':u\mapsto\begin{cases}
(t\circ r)(u),&\text{if }u\in U_0\\
u,&\text{if }u\in U_1\;.
\end{cases}$$

Note that any point $\langle 0,y\rangle$ on the left edge of $U_0$ is sent by $t\circ r$ to $\langle 1,-y\rangle$, precisely the point with which it is identified by $\sim$, so we can think of this point as ‘being’ $[\langle 0,y\rangle]=[\langle 1,-y\rangle]$. With this identification in mind it’s not too hard to see that $\psi\circ(p\upharpoonright U)=f$; this may make it a little easier to see what $\psi$ does.

In very informal physical terms, imagine that you’ve actually taken the strip $M_0$, glued it to the table along the strip $[0.49,0.51]\times A$, bent the righthand end up into a half cylinder, so that the edge $\{1\}\times A$ lies directly above the line $x=\frac12$, and then bent the lefthand end up similarly, given it a half twist, and identified the two ends to get a physical Möbius strip. Then $\psi$ amounts to performing the following physical steps:

1. Cut the Möbius strip along the line $x=\frac12$ and unfasten the strip $[0.49,0.5)\times A$ from the table. You now have a strip of dimensions $1\times 2a$ with one end fastened to the table at $(0.5,0.51]\times A$.
2. The strip still has a half twist; untwist it and stretch the strip out flat to the right of the glued section.

This is basically my $U'$ and the original $\psi[V]$.

The only points at which there is any real difficulty showing continuity of $\psi$ (or $t\circ r$) are the points where $\sim$ identifies two distinct points of $M_0$. If $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small to avoid running into the upper and lower edges of $U_0=\psi[V]$, $(t\circ r)^{-1}[B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)]$ is the union of $B(\langle 0,-y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_0$ and $B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_1$, a set that is open in $U$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it has been very helpful. However in the last paragraph $(t\circ r)^{-1}[B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)]$ should not be instead $(t\circ r)[B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)]$, I guess you meant $B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)$, right?

Comment: In the last paragraph you are proving that $\psi$ is open instead of continuous, right?

Comment: @PedroGomes: No, I meant what I wrote: it’s part of what’s needed to show that $t\circ r$ is continuous. Were you thinking of proving instead that it’s open? Ah, now I see from your second comment that you were. That’s also possible.

Comment: Is $[B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)]$ a subset of M(the moebius strip) or is it a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Because then $(t\circ r)^{-1}[B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)]$ is the union of $B(\langle 0,-y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_0$ and $B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_1$ however $U_0\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Since $\psi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^2\to M$ I deduced it was a typo to write $(t\circ r)^{-1}$ instead of $t\circ r$

Comment: @PedroGomes: Here $B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)$ is a subset of $U'=\psi[V]$ and hence of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance insofar! My problem is that  $B(\langle 0,-y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_0$ and $B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_1$ are also subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ once $U_0$ and $U_1$ were defined to be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Should they be instead subsets of $M$, hence my confusion.

Comment: @PedroGomes: Yes, but they respect the identification $\sim$: it ‘pastes’ them together to give an open ball in $M$. My answer was more an attempt to make that easier to visualize than actually to start the proof itself. (I probably should have tried harder to make that clear.)

Comment: Then I could use the $p:\mathbb{R}^2\to M$ in order to "paste" the two open sets B(\langle 0,-y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_0 and $B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_1$ in the following way $A=p(B(\langle 0,-y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_0)=p(B(\langle 0,-y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_0)$ so that $A$ is open by the quotient mapping since union of the two sets was open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Right?

Comment: @PedroGomes: What you really want is $$p[f^{-1}[(B(\langle 0,-y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_0)\cup(B(\langle 1,y\rangle,\epsilon)\cap U_1)]]\;;$$ **that** will be an $\epsilon$ ball around $[\langle 0,-y\rangle]=[\langle 1,y\rangle]$ in $M$. (My internet keeps going out today, so I’m rather distracted and may not be able to respond at all promptly (or clearly!).